# Submit data to 2 lists if checkbox is checked

Tags: infopath, list-form, data, submit

I am relative new to Sharepoint and coding so please forgive my ignorance.

I designed a form with InfoPath Designer 2013 and the last field is a Checkbox (Boolean type). What I am trying to do is that after the submission of the form to a list (list1), if the checkbox is checked, it should submit part of the form data (Title, Date, Description) to another list (list2).

Any ideas how to do that through Sharepoint Designer or InfoPath?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Easier to do with SharePoint designer workflow.

- Create a workflow for List1, and have it run when new items are created.
- In the workflow step, add a 'If' condition to check if the checkbox is 'not empty' (which means it is checked)
- Add an action "Create Item in List". Which is List2
- In there, you can include what fields are supposed to be updated as per List1. 
  Set the field and value accordingly. Where, Data Source in the lookup would be "Current Item".

Comment: Just want to add one thing to this answer... You will need to promote the fields from your InfoPath form in order to be able to use them in the workflow.